# Change schema attribute cardinality based on another attribute

Tags: clojure, datomic

I have the following pseudo schemas:

A)

```
-- Cost-schedule: FRE494
   -- Periodic: false
   -- Type: Fixed
   -- Value: 70.00
   -- CCY GBP
```

B)

```
-- Cost-schedule: GHK999
   -- Periodic: true
   -- Period start: 01/04/2015
   -- Period end: 30/04/2015
   -- Type: Promise
   -- Filled: false
   -- Value: 0.00
   -- CCY: GBP
```

I am trying to avoid any kind of nasty hierarchy with a super class "Cost-Schedule" with sub-classes "Periodic" and "One-off". Firstly, I am using clojure which is not OO. Also don't want to fall into the Liskov Substitution trap.

So, as a newbie to Datomic, is there a way to dynamically change the schema so that an attributes cardinality is modified based on another attribute value. In this case, if Periodic is "false" we don't need to have Period-Start, Period-End. If Periodic is "true" then we need to enforce having values for these attributes.

My gut says, this is not possible. If not, how can I enforce this in the DB? It appears to me that if I have to explicitly validate the transaction before submitting it to the transactor then I am really just defining a schema outside of the constraints of Datomic which doesn't appear to be wise, given that many micro-systems will be writing/reading from the DB and coordinating humans to write 'correct' code is difficult!

Any help on how to overcome this challenge very gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two sub-answers to your question.

The first is that Datomic does not define "objects". It is really closer to a plain map.  Your entity B has 3 fields that entity A does not.  That is fine and is not controlled in any way by Datomic. Each attribute-value pair can be added to any entity independently from any other entity. Just because one map has 4 entries, it has no relationship to another map having 7 entries, even if all of the keys in map A are also in map B.

The 2nd sub-answer is that your app must do all validation & integrity checking - Datomic won't. There is no analogue to "UNIQUE NOT NULL" in SQL, etc.  However, Datomic does support [Database Functions](http://docs.datomic.com/database-functions.html) which have a chance to abort any transaction that fails a user-supplied test. So, this is one way of enforcing data integrity checks.

Please also check out [Tupelo Datomic](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/tupelo/datomic.adoc), a library I wrote to make using Datomic more effortless.